# jquery ajax form validation on submission then continue on to form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Here is what I'm trying to do,

Capture my form submission post it to my ajax processing for form validation (without a page reload obviously)

then if the ajax server side doesn't return an array of errors (data in the code below) go ahead with the actual form submission. The 'return false' at the bottom of the snippet should prevent the jquery default behavior (which is to submit the form)

I've tried just `return true` if we don't get any errors but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Here is what I got so far:

```
$('.submit').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/processform_ajax",
        data: $(':input').serializeArray(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != '') {
                $("#response span").html("");
                $('.highlightbox').removeClass('highlightbox');
            } else {
                $('#myform').submit();
            }
        },
        error: function(error, txt) {
            alert("Error: " + error.status);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What's your HTML/form look like?

Comment: on your processform_ajax what does it return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handle this two different ways:

First, do front end validation with the wonderful [Jquery Inline validation tool](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)  This step knocks out 95% of the problems before having to get tricky with PHP and Jquery.

Second, I submit my values from the form to the script.  Let the PHP (in my case) do the "thinking" on validation.  If it's incorrect, I return that information in a json_encoded string for the success function.  I build a case (if `data.valid == true` for example) then display error flags.  Else, do success steps and notify the user in the UI.

I think the key in your case is to ensure that the data coming back is json_encoded.  FYI, I've noticed some very random issues with json_encode sometimes causing issues with the data return function due to square brackets, which are entirely valid but sometimes cause non-erroring faults.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you. I had all this sorted out really, but your answer led to me finding out the problem was the way I was dealing with the JSON response. Basically I think JS was throwing an error because on the AJAX return if everything was good, i wasn't returning the data array, which was causing the JS problems with the "if" statement when 'data' is undefined, so the $('#myform').submit was never executing. setting data.valid == true on no errors fixed the issue. I hope that made sense :)